# How can I dynamically apply the "left" px to a div's width, within the same parent element, using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, dynamic

So, in the most basic terms, I have this set up:

```
<div id=parent_element>

    <div class="child_one"></div>
    <div class="child_two"></div>

</div>
```

Currently, .child_one has a left css value that changes dynamically. What I'd like to do is keep the width value of .child_two exactly the same as the left value of .child_one, on the fly.

I've tried this:

```
$('.child_two').width($(this).parent($(this).closest('.child_one').css("left")));
```

...but, to no avail. Am I even on the right track or is there a better way of doing this?

**More accurate code:**

```
<div class="mCSB_draggerContainer">
    <div oncontextmenu="return false;" style="position: absolute; width: 266px; left: 0px;" class="mCSB_dragger">
        <div style="position:relative;" class="mCSB_dragger_bar"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="mCSB_draggerRail"></div>
    <div class="slide_progress" style="width: 0px;"></div>
</div>


<script>
    $('.mCSB_draggerContainer').append("<div class=slide_progress></div>");

    var progress_width = $('.mCSB_dragger').css('left');
    $('.slide_progress').css('width', progress_width);
</script>
```

Also, I should have mentioned that the .slide_progress div is added with jQuery .append().

Comment: Just to be more clear. What is "left" value. Are you referring to left margin? Or left padding? Or do you mean the total width of the element to the left?

Comment: seems your problem here is you get a value with px from left but you can paste it on width directly becaus it doesn't handle units

Comment: @KrisHollenbeck Referring to the actual left value. So, if .child_one is set at left:100px, then i need the width of .child_two to be width:100px also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems your problem here is you get a value with `px` from `left` but you can't paste it on width directly because it doesn't handle units : see more here [Width()](http://api.jquery.com/width/)

You can do this :

```
var twoWidth = $('.child_one').css('left');
$('.child_two').css('width', twoWidth);
```

With this you're getting some value of `left` on `px` and then assign it to the `width` of second div.

To make this work you need to identify the correct place on your function or your code: here are some examples:

[Fire event with Button Click](http://jsfiddle.net/Fw2vQ/13/)

[Fire event on Time](http://jsfiddle.net/Fw2vQ/17/)

Comment: So, this seems to work except it needs to be dynamic. I see that it's placing width:0 inline with child_two, because on pagre load, child_one is set at left:0. I need it to change dynamically. (child_one is a draggable sliding element).

Comment: so it depends directly on your handler can you post more code or a fiddle?

Comment: If it needs to be dynamic and faked since you can't use the functions handler, you can setTimeout.

Comment: @glenn you can check the examples i add on the answer